# can I display the forms in this for loop without putting the for loop in the templates?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to set this formset from the view because I need it to go out with initial data that the user doesn't see and cant change but this is for multiple people, based on whats in the database(and the user has to input their score for each person). I have trouble saving it if I do the for loop in the template, is there a way to display all of the forms instead of just the last one when I do the for loop in the views?

```
class heatform(modelform):

 class Meta:
    model = score
    fields = ["score"]
```

View:

```
couple_hreg = couple.objects.all()


FormSet = modelformset_factory(score, form = heatform)
for X in couple_hreg:
    form = FormSet(initial=[{'couple_r1':X.pk ,'number':X.number}],queryset = score.objects.none())
```

---

template:

```
 {{form}}
```